# Algebra minimum value problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$ and $b$ are positive real variables, whose sum is a constant $k$, then the minimum value of $$\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{a} \right) \left(1+ \frac{1}{b} \right)}=?$$

Comment: cannnot understand anything.....plss explain...@ user148176

Comment: Hint: if $a$ and $b$ are positive real variables whose sum is a constant $k$, can you find the **maximum** value of $ab$?

Comment: The maximum value is k + 2/k as ab is maximum when a=b=k/2. How do I find minimum value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe that

$$\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{a} \right) \left( 1+\frac{1}{b} \right)}=\sqrt{\left( \frac{a+1}{a} \right) \left(\frac{b+1}{b} \right)}=\sqrt{\frac{ab+(a+b)+1}{ab}}=\sqrt{\frac{ab+k+1}{ab}}. $$

Comment: The maximum value is k + 2/k as ab is maximum when a=b=k/2. How do I find minimum value ?

Comment: @user148176 you have to make $ab$ as large you can.

Comment: Do you mean that k + 2/k is actually the minimum value ?